# WebGL code not working- blank page

Tags: webgl

I´ve started working with WebGL and javascript in these last few days and I´ve stumbled across a problem that I have no idea how to solve.I don´t know why, but everytime that I´m trying to run this program a html opens with nothing unless a blank page.The program should be drawing points when I click on the screen.

```js
 //ClickedPoints.js
 //Vertex shader program


 var VSHADER_SOURCE =
   'attribute vec4 a_Position;\n' +
   'void main() {\n' +
   ' gl_Position = a_Position;\n' +
   ' gl_PointSize= 10.0; \n' +
   '}\n';

 //Fragment shader program

 var FSHADER_SOURCE =
   'void main() {\n' +
   'gl_FragColor= vec4(1.0,0.0,0.0,1.0);\n' +
   '}\n';

 function main() {

   //Retrieve <canvas> element

   var canvas = document.getElementById('webgl');

   //Get the rendering context for WebGL

   var gl = getWebGLContext(canvas);

   if (!gl) {
     console.log('Failed to get the rendering context for WebGL');
     return;
   }

   //Initialize shaders

   if (!initShaders(gl, VSHADER_SOURCE, FSHADER_SOURCE)) {
     console.log('Failed to initialize shaders');
     return;
   }

   //Get the storage location of attribute variable

   var a_Position = gl.getAttribLocation(gl.program, 'a_Position');

   if (a_Position < 0) {
     console.log('Failed to get the storage location of a_Position');
     return;
   }

   //Register function (event handler) to be called on a mouse press

   canvas.onmousedown = function(ev) {
     click(ev, gl, canvas, a_Position);
   };

   gl.clearColor(0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0)


   //Clear <canvas>

   gl.Clear(gl.COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

 }

 var g_points = []; //The array for a mouse press

 function click(ev, gl, canvas, a_Position) {

   var x = ev.clientX; //x coordinate of a mouse pointer
   var y = ev.clientY; //y coordinate of a mouse pointer
   var rect = ev.target.getBoundingClientRect(); //getting the location of canvas, including its start point

   x = ((x - rect.left) - canvas.width / 2) / (canvas.width / 2); //adjusting the x and y axis in these two lines
   y = (canvas.height / 2 - (y - rect.top)) / (canvas.height / 2);

   //Store the coordinates to g_points array

   gpoints.push(x);
   gpoints.push(y);

   //Clear <canvas>

   gl.Clear(gl.COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

   var len = g_points.length; //the lenght of the array for the times the mouse was pressed

   for (var i = 0; i < len; i += 2) {

     //Pass the position of a point to a_Position variable

     gl.vertexAttrib3f(a_Position, g_points[i], g_points[i + 1], 0.0);

     //Draw a point

     gl.drawArrays(gl.POINTS, 0, 1);
   }
 }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <title>Draw points with mouse click</title>
</head>

<body onload="main()">
  <canvas id="webgl" width="400" height="400">
    Please use a browser that supports "canvas"
  </canvas>

  <script src="webgl-utils.js"></script>
  <script src="webgl-debug.js"></script>
  <script src="cuon-utils.js"></script>
  <script src="ClickedPoints2.js"></script>

</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might find it helpful to use the JavaScript DevTools built into your browser. All browsers have them. [Here's Chrome's](https://developer.chrome.com/devtools).

In particular you want the [JavaScript console](https://developer.chrome.com/devtools/docs/console).

If you had looked there you'd have seen several errors like

```
Uncaught TypeError: gl.Clear is not a function
```

Because it's `clear` not `Clear`

Also

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: gpoints is not defined
```

Because you defined it as `g_points` above not `gpoints`

Also BTW `initScripts` is doing something horrible. It's creating a WebGL shader program and attaching it to the WebGLRenderingContext object by doing

```
gl.program = someProgram
```

I can see this is the case because you have code that says

```
var a_Position = gl.getAttribLocation(gl.program, 'a_Position');
```

Why is this bad? Because most WebGL apps have multiple shader programs. Instead `initScripts` should return a program

```
var program = initScripts(...)
```

Then you'd call

```
var a_Position = gl.getAttribLocation(program, 'a_Position');
```

And

```
gl.useProgram(program);
```

to use it.